# Run Spark on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

From MacOS, I downloaded Zeppelin 0.6.2 with all-interpreters.

Start daemon, open browser, type a spark command, and I got:

"Prefix not found" error.

What this error means?

[image]

Comment: did you check if the interpreter is enabled ?

Comment: Yes it is, binding settings are setup correctly as well

Comment: check zeppelin logs

Answer (score 1):

I saw many users face "prefix not found" error since they didn't click "Save" button under interpreter binding page. You can open/close the interpreter binding page by clicking "gear icon" on top-right side in the note.